# Keep main view controller (root) in portrait orientation and rotate child controllers

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

What I'am trying to achieve:

Main view controller should always be in portrait orientation and all presented controllers should rotate according to the device orientation.

Also child controller can be transparent so I want to see the main view controller under the child view controller

Some code:

FirstViewController

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

SecondViewController

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .allButUpsideDown
}
```

I tried a few options of modalPresentationStyle

1. secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

Result: main controller rotates with child

2. secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

Result: main controller is hiding after opening a child controller

Project example: https://github.com/alexseroshtan/RotationTest

Comment: Will `mainController` change its content when showing `secondVC`?

Comment: @trungduc yes, main controller can contain dynamic content, not just static view